# Изменить кодировку в nodejs. CP1251/1252 в UTF-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка, npm, iconv

Никак не получается изменить кодировку, у меня есть парсер, выводит информацию в консоль в нормальном виде (кодировка либо CP1251, либо CP1252), но эту информацию мне надо отправлять в телеграмм по API. Мне вылазит ошибка, что кодировка должна быть UTF-8.

```
var opt = {
  url:url,
  headers:headers,
  encoding: 'binary'
};

message = iconv.decode(message, "cp1251");
```

Если делать так:

```
 message = iconv.decode(message, "utf8");
```

то выводит иероглифы

Comment: А если сделать message = iconv.encode(message, "utf8").toString();

Comment: "Äîáàâëåíî ÷åðåç 1 ìèíóòó 31 ñåêóíäó" - вот что выводит

Comment: Если у тебя iconv-lite то думаю надо так сделать - var message = iconv.decode(message, "cp1251");
var message = iconv.encode(message, "utf8").toString();

Comment: Да, спасибо, в консоль выводится в utf8 теперь, но вот когда отправляется в телеграмм, то уже там сообщение такое: 
">102;5=> G5@57 2 <8=CBK 3 A5:C=4K". В чем ошибка? И можете пояснить, зачем надо делать decode, а потом encode? Почему сразу encode не срабатывает?

Comment: надо смотреть что не так с телеграмом , если строка UTF8 то проблем быть не должно. Два раза потому что сначала мы как-бы преобразовываем в свой формат, а потом из него делаем ту кодировку которая нужна

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот простой пример для [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite)

```
var message = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(message, "cp1251"), "utf8").toString();
```

Comment: Создал PHP файл на своем сервере. Кодировка файла UTF-8. Направляю через request get - запрос с var message = iconv.encode(iconv.decode("Привет", "cp1251"), "utf8").toString(); 
Выводит %1F@825B

Comment: что за PHP?, тут же js. По  поводу строки "%1F@825B" надо смотреть как она передаётся. Без более полного кода сложно сказать где возникает проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ, отмеченный, как принятый -- полный привет логике, и полное досвидание производительности.

Проблема решается неочевидно. Помимо кодировки исходника (исходные данные на источнике), многое зависит от того, каким инструментом забираете источник: `node-fetch`, `request`, `axios`, `unirest`,... В случае, если данные читаются из файла, там данное решение тоже пройдет, но... там отдельная история.

Суть проблемы в том, что Привет может прилететь и из заголовков (`headers`) ответа (`response`) и даже из содержимого ответа (в случае `XML` -- обязательно). Я двое суток смотрел на буквы `э` на местах всех кириллических знаков, пока не расковырял исходники всех этих фетчей и реквестов, которые думать не думают о других кодировках, кроме `utf8` и других форматах данных, кроме `json`, и то -- `JSON` обязательно должен быть `utf8`, даже `Unicode` ему нельзя быть. Как в песенке про папу, который может быть кем угодно, но мамой не может быть. Хуже всего, если все-таки -- думают, но полагают, что все решено.

Далее, важно в какой консоли вы смотрите ответы Ноды: Windows (XP, Vista, 7|8, 10 - ждут сюрпризы), xterm? У Вас LINUX! О! Как хорошо, что Вы не знаете, что такое KOI-8, а Ваши учителя даже про KOI-7. Относительно ровно предсказать вывод без танцев с большим шаманским бубном можно в консолях RHEL^7(CentOs^7, Fedora^17), Ubuntu^12, MacOs^X. С другими не знаком, либо неоднозначно.

Еще вопрос - удалённо если смотрите на терминал, то какой протокол, какой терминальный клиент? Допустим, что с терминалом и кодировками на терминале хорошо.

Ожидаемое решение можно получить только ручками через нативный http или node-fetch, и только тогда, когда входные данные обрабатываются как буфер.

Вот рабочий макет для песочницы. Просто поиграйтесь с вариантами (ответы функции `cnw8`), которых на просторах интернетов вагон. Почти все они -- неправильные, работают только два: один здесь, а другой у Майкла Джексона.

```js
const url = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp';
// если хвост отдает еще и заголовок 'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=windows-1251'
// тут совсем труба с инструментами, проявляющими инициативу по обработке данных
// т.е. axios, unirest, fetch, node-fetch в режиме text, все это НЕ БУДЕТ РАБОТАТЬ

const fs = require('fs-extra'); // промифицированный вывод на диск без заморочек
// просто мне лень еще и промис расписывать, да и пример загромождать некчему

// fetch нативный, без заморочек, промисы -- родные, нодовские, т.е. -- V8
// body -- buffer, который нужно обработать ручками
// еще лучше -- взять нативный http
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 

const iconv = require('iconv-lite'); // тот самый конвертер

/**
 * вывод в файл без заморочек, что получили, то и сохранили
 */
function saveResult(buf, fileName = 'data.xml') {
  fs.outputFile(fileName, buf);
  return buf;
}
/**
 * просто просмотр полученного, отдаем, что получили, чтобы не рвать цепочку
 */
function showResult(res) {
  console.log(res);
  console.log('\n============================================\n');
  return res;
}
/**
 * собственно перекодировка Win --> Utf8
 */
function cnw8(buf) {
  return iconv.decode(Buffer.from(buf, 'binary'), 'cp1251').toString();
}

fetch(url)
  .then(res => showResult(res))
  .then(res => res.buffer())
  .then(res => saveResult(res))
  .then(res => showResult(res))
  .then(res => cnw8(res))
  .then(res => showResult(res))
  .catch(err => console.error('\n--------------------\nПля!\n\n', err));
```

```html
*
```